# Paragraphs module decoupled structure

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I'm looking to use the Paragraphs Drupal 8 module with a decoupled installation of Drupal 8 but would like the structure made in the admin area to be output in the JSON API responses.

How can I modify the JSON API responses from Drupal 8 to include this page structure data?

If anyone wants to know, having it decoupled & outputting structure information is a requirement I've been given.

Comment: Couple of things it would be useful to know - what do you define as "page structure data" in your installation, and what provides/links that structure to paragraphs?

Comment: @Clive So the idea is to create a page then use paragraphs to, for example, allow the user to add content for a "two column" paragraph layout and to a "two column" paragraph layout, or any other layout and reorder them. The order of these paragraph layouts would then be shown in the JSON API output so the front-end knows what layout is used and in what order.

I hope that clears things up a little.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a compound document, the JSON:API mechanism that provides other referenced entities in a resource (e.g. a "page" content node that references other paragraphs). This is done via adding an `include` query parameter with a value that refers to a field's relational ID. An inclusion request will add an `included` array property with the related entity resource objects.

See the docs on [Includes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/jsonapi/includes) in the JSON:API docs for more concrete examples in action.

Since you mentioned it, ordering included resources isn't possible (IIRC); you might be able to infer order based on the Paragraph field. JSON:API is designed for minimal configuration and maximum adherence to the JSONAPI spec so you're limited to a couple of mechanisms to modify the output of the structured data.

Comment: You said "ordering included resources isn't possible". Currently the order in `included` is the actual order corresponding to the paragraph-field deltas, but now I am wondering if I can rely on it? This is not specific to paragraphs, but to all multi-value fields, I guess.